# Imputation of Missing Value on Python for Consecutive NaN

Tags: python, numpy, imputation

Edit: I am now looking for a clean way to impute the missing value of my dataset on Python

```
     a       b         c
0    1       2         Falcon

1    np.nan   3        Falcon

2    np.nan   np.nan   Falcon
  
3    np.nan    4       Bird

4    np.nan   5        Bird
 
5    5        np.nan   Bird

6    6        7        Bird
```

I will need to impute using the following conditions based on their individual group.

(1) for missing values that has a value in its preceding **and** previous row, fill it by interpolating

(2) for missing values that has a value in its preceding **or** previous row, fill it with the preceding or previous row value

(3) for missing values that does not satisfy (1) and (2), fill it with 0

An example of the result will be

```
     a   b      c
0    1   2      Falcon

1    1   3      Falcon

2    0   3      Falcon
  
3    0   4      Bird

4    5   5      Bird

5    5   6      Bird

6    6   7      Bird
```

I have tried the code provided in the comment below, however i failed to set it via its respective group. How do I go about doing it in Python?

Comment: Do you have code for not so clean way? What kind of interpolation?

Comment: Linear interpolation. I am not sure how to create a function/loop for python to detect only the fields that satisfied the 3 conditions. I have tried "dataset.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True, limit=1)" to satisfy condition 2, but when i used this, it also fill in the missing value of row 5 np.nan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot imagine a single direct way, so I would use one pass for each of your requirements. The nice thing is that as each pass will fill in some values, following passes will not try to fill them:

1. for missing values that has a value in its preceding and previous row, fill it by interpolating

   ```
    df[df.isna()&(~df.shift().isna())&(~df.shift(-1).isna())] = df.interpolate()
   ```
2. for missing values that has a value in its preceding or previous row, fill it with the preceding or previous row value

   ```
    df[df.isna()&(~df.shift().isna())] = df.ffill()
    df[df.isna()&(~df.shift(-1).isna())] = df.bfill()
   ```
3. for missing values that does not satisfy (1) and (2), fill it with 0

   ```
    df.fillna(0)
   ```

With your sample data, it gives as expected:

```
     a    b
0  1.0  2.0
1  1.0  3.0
2  0.0  3.5
3  0.0  4.0
4  5.0  5.0
5  5.0  6.0
6  6.0  7.0
```

It does require 4 operations, but all of them are vectorized, so the global processing time should be tolerable.

Comment: Hi Serge, thanks for your solution. However, could i check what does the code below mean. I understand that df.shift means shifting the index by the period specified, however the part that confused is that why by shifting the dataframe, it will satisfy the condition "for missing values that has a value in its preceding and previous row, fill it by interpolating": 

df[df.isna()&(~df.shift().isna())&(~df.shift(-1).isna())]

Comment: `shift` shifts the row one position down or up (with -1), `isna` tests if a value is nan, and `~` negates the test. Finaly `&` is the logical and...

Comment: i have edited by question. I realised that i have to impute the missing value based on their individual group. May i know how can i group the dataframe first before interpolate? I attempted to use df.group('c'). However, this does not return me a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

This is not complete answer yet, but a couple of hints. Assuming we deal with a single array here (eg, a).

First, concatenate [nan] at the beginning and at the end of a to get a1. This will simplify applying imputation rules.

Second, you can now take three arrays a1[:-2], a1[1:-1], a1[2:] to have all three moving window values.

Of course, you will need to write a function to impute the value based on those three values, but it will be simple:

```
def impute(xprev, x, xnext):
   if not isnan(x):
      return x
   # the rest of the logic here left as an exercise
```

Hint 2: There probably are more efficient constructs (like np.stack), but one simple way to have all three values is the normal `zip`:

```
result_list = [impute(prev, this, next) for (prev, this, next) in zip(a1[:-2], a1[1:-1], a1[2:])]
# turn list to array or you can use np.fromiter(( impute(...) for ... ), np.float64) to make array directly from iterable
```

I hope those hints are enough to build the solution.

In the solution above I applied a couple of general patterns, which I discovered practicing programming:

1. Padding with convenient stop values instead of checking indexes for borders
2. Using `zip` to have small-sized moving windows

Note. It's also possible to generate indexes for the extended array (a1) instead of using zip or stack. So I believe there will be other answers with more optimizations as Numpy has a lot of functions to offer. Also the `impute` above can probably be made into `ufunc` and applied to stacked shifted arrays - however, without profiling it's hard to tell whether it will be more efficient than the simple list comprehension above or corresponding solution with an index.